# Remove file extension

Tags: php, mysql

I have this:

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$skin_name = $_POST['nameXXXXXC'];
$price = $_POST['amount'];
$by = $_COOKIE['userName'];

$KS84JMCN = substr($name, 0,strrpos($name,'.'));

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO `Skins`(
    `Name`,
    `Skin_Name`,
    `Price`,
    `Made_By`
) VALUES (
    '$KS84JMCN',
    '$name',
    '$price',
    '$by'
)");
```

But it's not removing the file extension, in the database, under 'Name' is the file name but with .png at the end, so it's not removing the file extension.

Comment: Beware: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks; it will crash or behave incorrectly if any of your input fields contain quote characters. You **must** properly escape any input data before passing it to a SQL query.

Comment: Remove all un necessary code from the question. leave only line number 1 and line number 5.
And to solve that, put an echo $name after line number 1 and after `$KS84JMCN = substr...` to see your issues.
Such questions are supposed to be asked here, at least before proper debugging effort was done

Comment: Why do you use such an odd (`$KS84JMCN`) variable name?

Comment: What you're doing doesn't appear to be wrong specifically: http://codepad.org/BUB1KyL3

Comment: Accept some previous answers please

Comment: I echoed the "KS84JMCN" variable after uploading 'test.png' and it resulted in 'test', however, it's still coming up as test.png in the database.

Comment: You mean you `exit($KS84JMCN);` right before the `INSERT` `mysql_query()` and it's right, but right after that it's not? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: What? I didn't put a single exit(); function there.

Comment: Also, you might want to use a logged-in `SESSION` value instead of a `COOKIE` value, as a user could tamper with the `COOKIE` value. and I echo that you have SQL injection-worthy code (use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or the PHP PDO library).

Comment: You're not following what I'm saying with `exit()`. Is the value you checked the one that is set immediately before your `mysql_query()` or not? An `exit()` a line before is a common way to check this (if low rent).

Comment: In other words, unless you have something like `pic.png.png` or some other condition that's not demonstrated above, I don't see how you could end up with what you say with the code above. And please, review previous questions and accept appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you noticed you're inserting the value of `$name` into the `Skin_name` column, and `$skin_name` isn't used at all? Sure the `Name` column doesn't contain the filename without extension?

Answer (score 4):

```
$name = 'lol.lol.jpg';

echo pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // lol.lol
```

Comment: Yes, but the code the OP has *should* work: http://codepad.org/BUB1KyL3 At least as well as this would.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add this, I'm a newbie at this

Comment: unless the image name was image.jpeg.jpeg :-DDD